# Derivative of discontinuous trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, partial-derivative, continuity

given the following function as an toy example:

$f(\alpha,\beta) = \frac{c_1 \cdot sin(\alpha - asin(c_2))}{sin(\alpha-\beta-c_3)}$

where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are some constants.

Knowing the points of discontinuity, I would get in a next step the derivative of this example by performing a partial derivative according to $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

For this purpose I'd like to exclude the points of discontinuity from the derivation. Is this possible to partially derivate $f(\alpha,\beta)$ only for specific intervals of $\alpha,\beta$? My primary purpose is not to get a explicit solution for the toy function but rather to see if it is possible -  and if yes - how one can perform partial derivatives on such a discontinuous trigonometric function.

Thank you in advance for any directing hints.
Dan

Comment: Don't bother trying to remove the discontinuities.  Just find your partial derivatives.  The partial derivatives will not exist along the line $\alpha - \beta = n \pi + c_3$